# What is the name of this hydroponic plant?

Tags: identification, propagation, hydroponic, cuttings

I have this plant at my office, where it is having a lot of children. Every time that I get some leaves from the plant and put them in a bottle with water, the leaves get some roots and don't die after more than a month without soil.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The plant has small flowers that are open very few time and roll over themselves in a spiral. It also has seeds that are directly growing in a bundle of three.

Answer (score 6):

It's a [*Chlorophytum comosum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophytum_comosum), commonly known as Spider Plant. It's not a 'hydroponic' plant though - the fact that it survives in water when you're getting it to grow roots is true of many plants. It will, though, prefer to be potted up into a growing medium eventually.

Comment: Spider plants are the ultimate beginner house plant!