# What kind of plant is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants

This clipping was taken from a plant hanging at a friend's house. The plant had many such bulb-like growths coming from stalks that were offshooting from the main plant (hanging from the pot).

[image: clipping that didn't need to be clipped]

Comment: Please note that the plant grows quickly and tends to fill the pot with thick white roots. If you leave the plant in this glass (?) jar, it might even cause it to break in a few months, mine shattered a clay pot. Plastic might be a better choice in this case. Also, your pot seems very wet. While the plantlets need good moisture to develop the roots, overwatering gan cause root rot. Consider replanting once the plantlet is established, allowing for good drainage.

Comment: Also http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/8427/26

Comment: @Stephie thanks for the comment. The plant has been in that glass for a couple weeks, and I've started to transition it to soil. In order to allow for a smooth transition my strategy is to remove a bit of water every day, and replace it with an equal amount of soil. Thanks for the tip on the plastic pot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [*chlorophytum comosum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophytum_comosum), commonly called **spider plant** or **hen-and-chicken**.

The plant is easy to care for and thrives best at typical indoor temperatures between 18-30 C / 65-90 F. It prefers indirect light, but can tolerate some sun, too. It's very "forgiving" and will even survive *occasional* drying out of the potting soil. Overwatering will lead to root rot, though. 
 It's plantlets (the "baby-plants") are an easy way of multiplying them. Usually spider plants are considered an excellent choice for beginners.

Spider plants are also known for their ability to purify air, Wikipedia states for example:

> Spider plants have also been shown to reduce indoor air pollution in the form of formaldehyde, and approximately 70 plants would neutralize formaldehyde production in a representative (ca. 160 m2) energy-efficient house.[14]

Comment: Glad you quoted the number of plants required. People tend to think one plant = clean air and it's not quite so easy.